# Bootscrap NavigationBar not showing drop-down menu and also menu on full screen isn't spaced from the title as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, cdn

The code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

The Bootscrap CDN links for js and html added to the head:

Expectation: 1.The navbar is suppose to be this spaced on desktop according to the image below [image: Expectation 1]
but instead I got this :[image: Result]

2. Also, on tablet and phone, the navbar should drop down menu when clicked, but mine doesn't, why?

[image: Expectation 2]

[image: Result 2]

PS: don't mind the background color.

I already explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `bg-dark` class to the nav. The code should be like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

I wrapped the `navbar-brand` in a div tag with a class named `container-fluid` as well.
*It just looks better*

Comment: Wow, I just copied your code and it did work in spacing the title and the menu option, although I still removed the bg-dark, since I don't want the background color. 

But the nav-bar is'nt still responsive, as the menu doesn't show up after clicking the nav-icon, anyways thanks for your help sir.